# AMD asm rep movs ecx=6

Tags: ассемблер

Хотелось бы прояснить следующее место в статье http://www.club155.ru/x86cmd/REP

> В некоторых моделях процессоров AMD при совпадении большого количества
>   условий (т.е. очень редко) возможна некорректная работа команды REP
>   MOVS с префиксом изменения размера адреса и начальным значением ECX
>   =6.

Какие это модели процессоров и вообще, что это за странная мистика, у самого найти упоминание подобного в англоязычном интернете не получилось.